# Cannot get url parameter in angular

Tags: angularjs

when I navigate to URL of my app:

```
http://localhost/RealSuiteApps/RealHelp/-1/Inbox/Detail?wonum=XXX
```

I want to get the value of **wonum**

Below is the constructor of my controller, I tried to use $location service as defined in angular documentation, **but it doesnt work, what is the problem?**

```
    constructor(private dataService: DataService, private $location) {
        var params = $location.search();
        var wonum = params.wonum;
        this.getWorkOrderDetail(wonum);
    }
```

[image]

Please note, the URL above is a link from one page to another, but it is not angular routing.

**UPDATE**

Adding # after Detail and before the question mark solves the issue

http://localhost/RealSuiteApps/RealHelp/-1/Inbox/Detail#/?wonum=BCB18405240

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect if its an angular application. Because an angular application will always append a # to the url and that is how angular maintains state of url's. $location.search() method will yield results only if the url is hash based.

Comment: Yes, indeed,adding # before the question mark solves the problem... thanks